# How to make Flow understand code written for Node.js?

Tags: flowtype

I'm just getting started with Flow, trying to introduce it into an existing Node codebase.

Here are two lines Flow complains about:

```
import Module from 'module';

const nodeVersion = Number(process.versions.node.split('.')[0]);
```

The warnings about these lines are, respectively:

```
module. Required module not found

call of method `split`. Method cannot be called on possibly null value
```

So it seems like Flow isn't aware of some things that are standard in a Node environment (e.g. `process.versions.node` is guaranteed to be a string, and there is *definitely* a Node builtin called `module`).

But then again, Flow's [configuration docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html) suggest it's Node-aware by default. And I have plenty of other stuff like `import fs from 'fs';` which does **not** cause any warning. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module `fs` works as expected because Flow comes with built-in definitions for it, see `declare module "fs"` here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/node.js#L624

Regarding `process.versions.node`, you can see in the same file that the `versions` key is typed as a map of nullable strings, with no mention of the specific `node` property: `versions : { [key: string] : ?string };`. So you'll need to either make a PR to improve this definition, or adjust your code for the possibility of that value being null.

I guess the answer about module "module" is obvious now – there are no built-in definitions for that module in Flow in `lib/node.js`. You could write your own definitions, and optionally send a PR with them to the Flow team. You can also try searching github for these, someone might have done the work already.

That `lib` directory is very useful by the way, it has Flow definitions for DOM and other stuff as well.

Comment: What if you're too lazy to add new definitions to Flow, and you just want the errors to go away, and you don't want to add `// $FlowFixMe` everywhere?